# How to add <ul> to a group of li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some markup like below

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 someclass">

     <li id="app-105">Find Friends</li>
     <li id="app-107">Buy Tickets,Pay Cover Charges</li>
     <li id="app-3">Pre-purchase bottle service</li>
     <li id="app-4">Book VIP Services</li>
     <li id="app-5">Buy Merchandise</li>
     <li id="app-6">Toast Friends worldwide</li>
     <li id="app-7">Notify Services &amp; split the tab</li>

</div>
```

Now I want to make it like this

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 someclass">

    <ul class="ajax-terms">

      <li id="app-105">Find Friends</li>
      <li id="app-107">Buy Tickets,Pay Cover Charges</li>
      <li id="app-3">Pre-purchase bottle service</li>
      <li id="app-4">Book VIP Services</li>
      <li id="app-5">Buy Merchandise</li>
      <li id="app-6">Toast Friends worldwide</li>
      <li id="app-7">Notify Services &amp; split the tab</li>

   </ul>

</div>
```

Note: Ids like `app-105` may change dynamically like `app-200`,`app-201` etc. and more `li`'s can be added in future.

How can I solve it with plain JavaScript or jQuery?

Any help to start will be appreciated.

Comment: Where is the markup coming from? It's invalid, `li` elements *can't* be direct children of `div`. If you load that into a browser, the browser is free to relocate those elements as it sees fit.

Comment: Ofcourse,it cant be,during page load I need to add ul.

Comment: My point being: If it's already been processed by the browser when you do that, the browser is perfectly within its rights to move those `li` elements elsewhere -- **before** you get a chance to move them. Chrome doesn't seem to (at least, not in my answer), but...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[`wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/)**

1. Iterate over all div using **[`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/)**
2. get all `li` inside using **[`children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/)**
3. Wrap it with `ul` using **[`wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/)**

```js
$('.someclass').each(function() {
  $(this).children('li').wrapAll($('<ul/>', {
    class: 'ajax-terms'
  }));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 someclass">

  <li id="app-105">Find Friends</li>
  <li id="app-107">Buy Tickets,Pay Cover Charges</li>
  <li id="app-3">Pre-purchase bottle service</li>
  <li id="app-4">Book VIP Services</li>
  <li id="app-5">Buy Merchandise</li>
  <li id="app-6">Toast Friends worldwide</li>
  <li id="app-7">Notify Services &amp; split the tab</li>

</div>

<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 someclass">

  <li id="app-105">Find Friends</li>
  <li id="app-107">Buy Tickets,Pay Cover Charges</li>
  <li id="app-3">Pre-purchase bottle service</li>
  <li id="app-4">Book VIP Services</li>
  <li id="app-5">Buy Merchandise</li>
  <li id="app-6">Toast Friends worldwide</li>
  <li id="app-7">Notify Services &amp; split the tab</li>

</div>
```

Comment: It's working correctly,wanted to mark upvoted but I don't have enough reputation:(

Answer (score 3):

What you've actually asked for is reasonably straightforward:

```js
$('li[id^="app-"]').parent().each(function() {
  $(this).children('li[id^="app-"]').wrapAll('<ul class="ajax-terms"></ul>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>First</p>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 someclass">

  <li id="app-105">Find Friends</li>
  <li id="app-107">Buy Tickets,Pay Cover Charges</li>
  <li id="app-3">Pre-purchase bottle service</li>
</div>
<p>Second</p>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 someclass">
  <li id="app-4">Book VIP Services</li>
  <li id="app-5">Buy Merchandise</li>
  <li id="app-6">Toast Friends worldwide</li>
  <li id="app-7">Notify Services &amp; split the tab</li>
</div>
```

**But**, the original markup is invalid, `li` elements *can't* be direct children of `div`. If you load that into a browser, the browser is free to relocate those elements as it sees fit. So be sure to test on your target browsers.

That won't handle cases where there's othe rstuff interspersed with the `li` elements, like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 someclass">
  <li id="app-4">Book VIP Services</li>
  <div>something else</div>                <!-- <================ Note -->
  <li id="app-5">Buy Merchandise</li>
  <li id="app-6">Toast Friends worldwide</li>
  <li id="app-7">Notify Services &amp; split the tab</li>
</div>
```

...but I didn't get the impression you had that.

Answer (score -1):

First i add a ul to your div, then i add all the li's to that ul that have the id's that contain the string "app"

```
$(".someclass").append("<ul id='yourUl'></ul>");
$("#yourUl").append($("[id*=app]"));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gx505qey/

Comment: '#yourUl',which ID you are referring?

Comment: you can see that id append a ul with the id='yourUl'